# What is this spice model? Is it a level shifter?

Tags: spice, gate-driving

Does anybody know what is this symbol in spice? [image]

I think this is something like Gate Drive or Level Shifter, but I want to know the exact part name or something like this part.

Comment: Can you give some context as to the design this is in? Possibly a full schematic? If the part number isn't given, that means you probably won't be able to find the exact part number used in this design. That's like saying "here's the schematic symbol for a transistor, what part number transistor is it".

Comment: But it's almost certainly not a level shifter.

Comment: Not to mention that ”spice” stands for a wide family of different software simulation tools, most of which allow for the creation of custom symbols.

Comment: Post the model parameters.

Comment: Given the symbol is shown to be interfacing between TTL levels and a MOSFET gate, why is this symbol not that of a gate-driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a gain block with an output limiter.  Gain is 4.  Upper and lower output limits are 20 and 0 respectively.

Comment: do you know its spice name??

Comment: Yes - it is called "gain limit".